# CSS opacity hides element in Firefox

Tags: css

I have this set for my disabled button:

```
cursor: not-allowed;
pointer-events: none;
opacity: 0.65;
box-shadow: none;
```

but in Firefox the button is invisible. What can cause it?

Comment: I believe something else is hiding it -> http://jsfiddle.net/5unL5god/

Comment: I think you're right, but I cannot find yet where is the problem. Maybe somewhere in javascript. I see only that I disable opacity, then the button shows up.

Comment: Have you tried to disable javascript?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot, because I use angularjs, and the app won't show up.

Comment: Try to add **visibility: visible;**, and prefixes for opacity, maybe that helps. Regards

Comment: I tried and it did not help. I had to make something wrong but I am not sure where.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated Firefox to the newest version 35 and it works now, I am not sure why it did not work in the version 34.